# Camera View as blurred background?

Tags: swift, xcode, camera

I try to use my camera's view (blurred) as background in my main menu.

I'm a beginner and have no idea how to do this...

please don't answer with "use ARSCNView"; I've tried this.

(best: send me a code in swift; I shouldn't be too long huh?)

After trying your code I have these errors: 
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36rXG.png)

Comment: For your next question please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, as SO is not a coding service to ask people to just provide code for your programming problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class TestingViewController: UIViewController {

    let session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) {
            do {
                try session.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))

            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)

            self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds

        }


        session.startRunning()

        let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
        blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(blurView)


    }

}
```

try this updated code and dont forget to add

> "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in your info.plist file

Comment: I tried your version but I have multiple errors. Can you tell me how to solve them? Thanks!

Comment: @user10219864 check now i have updated my answer and now it's working without any errors.

Comment: @user10219864 try with my new code and let me know if you get any errors I would like to solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much 4 answering and updating your code. I tried to fix your old code (and did it - except of 1 error). With your new code it nearly works! BUT: In my menu I have 6 buttons, which are not there now after the Blurred Camera view... How do I put the buttons on top of the blurred camera view?? Greetings

Comment: @user10219864 you can add those buttons programmatically on that view and u can set the frame based on ur requirements so u can achieve it easily and if this answer work for you then it would be cool if you upvote my answer